# Photoshop CS6 horizontal scrolling is too slow when selecting

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I use `Rectangular Marquee Tool` on a zoomed image and move the pointer out of the child window frame, the window starts scrolling. Vertical scrolling speed is just fine, but horizontal scrolling is a waaaay slower.

Did someone else notice that or it's just my system (CS6 on Win7)? Is there a setting, maybe some anisotropy factor?

Regards,

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Tech support is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.  Also the chances of finding someone else here using CS6 with Win7 (both very old) and on a similar spec PC are extremely slim to be honest.  Perhaps make sure your graphics card drivers are up to date. Make sure the image size is not absolutely huge. Close other applications you aren't using.

Comment: @BillyKerr Hi, I've just reproduced the issue on another machine with Win10. It seems to be a PS bug.

Comment: If it's a PS bug, it's one that will never be fixed. CS6 was released in 2012 & abandoned in 2017.